# populate struts2 jQuery grid dropdown column based on another dropdown column

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, struts2

I have searched for this kind of question before posting. Most of the answers found are not related to struts2 jQuery grid. Here is my situation:

1. I have successfully populated my dropdown boxes dynamically on initial load.
2. Now I want to reload one dropdown box based on the selection from the other dropdown box.
3. I am looking for a built in solution using the attributes/topics but I couldn't find one.

Can anyone share any solution to this?

Here is my code:

```
<sjg:gridColumn
    name="aut"
    index="aut"
    title="AUT"
    width="300"
    sortable="true"
    editable="true"
    edittype="select"
    surl="%{selectautsurl}"
    editoptions="{ dataUrl : '%{selectautsurl}' }"

   />
    <sjg:gridColumn
    name="eforms"
    index="eforms"
    title="Page/Eform"
    width="300"
    sortable="true"
    editable="true"
    edittype="select"
    surl="%{selecteformsurl}"
    editoptions="{ dataUrl : '%{selecteformsurl}' }"
    />
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm [struggling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21987390/1391249) for populating a drop down list on initial load. How did you populate the drop down list on initial page load?

Comment: What do `surl="%{selectautsurl}"` and `editoptions="{ dataUrl : '%{selectautsurl}' }"` mean here? How do they get item values and item labels of `<select>`?

Comment: the selectautsurl is defined in the <s:url var="selectautsurl" action="to_your_action_class" />. Please check this site: http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/FormatGrid

Comment: I don't precisely understand how specifying `editoptions="{ dataUrl : '%{selectautsurl}' }"` with `<sjg:grid>` can get item values and item labels of HTML `<select>`. If you're willing to, please answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21987390). I'm just looking for an idea. Just a precise idea can be an answer itself in its entirely.

Comment: you have to configure your action class in the struts a success value and it should point to a file that has select element. here is the struts config:
<action name="your_action_class" class="your_action_class">
   <result name="success">some.jsp</result>
  </action>   .... here is the jsp: <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<s:select headerValue="Select an item" headerKey="-1" list="this_will_come_from_your_action" theme="simple"/>

Comment: I have used `<s:select>` but here it is `<sjg:grid>` in which the list should appear while editing of rows. Can we have a stray `<s:select>` inside `<sjg:gridColumn>`? Sorry for so much concern but I don't understand precisely.

Comment: no you cannot... please read that wiki on the grid. check the attributes "edittype"... read thru the examples in the wiki. download the sample codes and play around with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to add `dataEvents` to the first `gridColumn` which changed value reloads the second `gridColumn`. You can do something like this,

```
<s:url id="url_id" namespace="/your_namespace" 
action="action_url_to_get_the_reloaded_list" >

    <sjg:gridColumn
        name="aut"
        index="aut"
        title="AUT"
        width="300"
        sortable="true"
        editable="true"
        edittype="select"
        surl="%{selectautsurl}"
        editoptions="{ dataUrl : '%{selectautsurl}', dataEvents: [type: 'change', fn: function(e) 
    {
                var url= '<s:property value="url_id" />' + '?your_attribute_sent_to_the_back=' + $('input#aut').val();, options;
                $.getJSON(url, function(retVal)
                {
                    options += '<option value="">&nbsp;</option>';
                    $.each(retVal.ur_returned_value, function(index, element)
                    {
                        options += '<option value="' + element.your_value + '">' + element.your_display_value + '</option>';
                    });     
                    $('input#eforms').html(options);
                });         
    }] }"

       />
```

I didn't test this solution but i think it will work.

Comment: thank you Uchenna for your inputs. I had some modifications though.

Answer (score 2):

thanks Uchenna for your comments. I took it and made some modifications and now it is working:

```
editoptions="{ dataUrl : '%{selectcavsurl}' ,
                                       dataEvents: [
                                       {  type: 'change', fn: function(value) {
                                    var params = 'selectedCAV='+this.value;
                                    $.get('eformsDropdown.action?'+params, function(data) 
                                    {
                                            var dropDown = document.getElementById('eforms');
                                            dropDown.innerHTML = data;
                                    });

                             }
                          }
                      ]     }"
```