# Using a drop-down list in an editable grid column using Struts2-jQuery-grid plugin

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid, struts2-jquery-plugin

I'm trying to populate a drop down list in a grid column using the [Struts2-jQuery-grid-3.7.0](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/detail?name=struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar&can=2&q=) plugin as follows.

```
<s:url id="dataURL" action="CategoryList" namespace="/admin_side"/>

<sjg:gridColumn name="subCategory.category.catName" 
                index="subCategory.category.catName" 
                edittype="select"
                searchtype="select" 
                formoptions="{label:'Select'}" 
                surl="%{dataURL}" 
                editoptions="{dataUrl : '%{dataURL}'}"
                editrules="{required: true}" 
                title="Category" width="200" 
                sortable="true" search="true" 
                editable="true" sorttype="text"/>
```

And the action where the `CategoryList` action is mapped is as follows.

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value="struts-default")
public final class CategoryList extends ActionSupport implements Serializable {
    @Autowired
    private final transient Service service = null;
    private List<Category>categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    @Action(value = "CategoryList",
            results = {
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location = "Product.jsp"),
                @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Product.jsp")},
            interceptorRefs = {
                @InterceptorRef(value = "defaultStack", params = {"validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true", "validation.excludeMethods", "load"})})
    public String load() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("load called...");
        categories = service.getCatgeoryList();
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

When a given edit link on the grid is clicked, the `load()` method is executed where a list of categories is loaded from the database.

The list in the grid however, displays nothing in edit mode (when the edit link is clicked). I cannot find relative examples that may demonstrate this kind of thing.

How to populate this drop down list especially, how to give this drop down labels using the `catName` property and values using the `catId` (of `Long` type) property separately (while `category` in the list has many other attributes)?

I don't find relevant examples to map a `java.util.List<E>` to `<sjg:grid>`.

---

<sub>`subCategory.category.catName` is a nested property of `Product` entity.</sub>

<sub>In this case, even after populating the list, it should also be noted that the display value of this column is `catName` (category name of type String). The value of the selected item however, to be set to an instance of `Product` should be `catId` (category id of type Long) which doesn't seem possible as the name of this column is `subCategory.category.catName`.</sub>

<sub>Intuitively, `catId` (`subCategory.category.catId`) would be mapped to `catName` (`subCategory.category.catName`) which would be wrong, if I could envision correctly as if the list were already populated.</sub>

Comment: Added struts2-jquery tag, because it has 31 followers while your other sj tags have 3 followers...

Comment: Please add answer(s), if someone has.

Answer (score 3):

In Struts 2, the HTML drop down list can be rendered via `<s:select>` tag. To auto select a default value for a drop down list, just declared a `“value”` attribute in the  tag, and set the default value accordingly.

***Example:***

A Java list to generate the select options for the drop down box.

```
//...
public class SelectAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<String> searchEngine;
    private String yourSearchEngine;

    //set default value
    public String getDefaultSearchEngine() {
        return "yahoo.com";
    }

    public SelectAction() { 
        searchEngine = new ArrayList<String>();
        searchEngine.add("google.com");
        searchEngine.add("bing.com");
        searchEngine.add("yahoo.com");
        searchEngine.add("baidu.com");
    }
    //...
}
```

tag to render the HTML drop down box. The `value=”defaultSearchEngine”` will call the corresponds Action class `getDefaultSearchEngine()` method to return a default search engine value.

Many Actions share common concerns. Some Actions need input validated. Other Actions may need a file upload to be pre-processed. Another Action might need protection from a double submit. Many Actions need [**drop-down lists**](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/) and other controls pre-populated before the page displays.

```
<s:select label="What's your favor search engine" 
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Search Engines"
    list="searchEngine" 
    name="yourSearchEngine" 
    value="defaultSearchEngine" />
```

In this example, the drop down box will auto select the “yahoo.com” as the default option.

***Add Struts2 jQuery Plugin Tag lib to your JSP***

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
```

***Enable jQuery Grid Plugin in your Head Tag***

```
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond" />
```

***update:***

Specify an Edit Url in your JSP

```
<s:url var="editurl" action="edit-grid-entry"/>
```

And enable Edit by setting following attributes in your JSP

```
 <sjg:grid ... editurl="%{editurl}" ...>
```

then define which Column should be editable

```
<sjg:gridColumn ...
  editable="true" 
  edittype="<type>" 
  editoptions="{<options>}"
  editrules="{<rules>}"
... />
```

***Example for an Edit Options:***

```
<sjg:gridColumn 
name="country" 
index="country" 
title="Country" 
editable="true" 
edittype="select" 
editoptions="{value:'France:France;USA:USA;Australia:Australia;Norway:Norway;Spain:Spain'}"/>
```

***Example for an Edit Rules:***

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="creditLimit"
              index="creditLimit"
              title="Credit Limit" 
              editable="true"
              editrules="{
                             number: true,
                             required: true,
                             minValue : 100.0,
                             maxValue : 10000.0
                         }"
              formatter="currency"/>
```

***update:1***

```
<select name="catid" size="15" id="dataURL" multiple="multiple">    
    <option value="1 - One ">1 - One </option> 
    <option value="2 - Two">2 - Two</option> 
    <option value="3 - Three">3 - Three</option> 
    <option value="4 - Four">4 - Four</option> 
    <option value="5 - Five">5 - Five</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: I know about this stray `<s:select>` but I need a drop down list inside `<sjg:gridColumn>`. This should have something to do with the attribute `editoptions="{dataUrl : '%{dataURL}'}"` or something else.

Comment: `editoptions` are dynamic. They should be populated from the database. Given the example in the question, `catId` as value and `catName` as label of `<select><option></option></select>`. How can this be dynamic - `editoptions="{value:'France:France;USA:USA;Australia:Australia;Norway:Norway;Spain:Spain'}"`?

Comment: The list is populated in the `CategoryList` class. It should be mapped to `editoptions`, `catId` as value and `catName` as label of `<select><option></option></select>`. Can this be done?

Comment: This cannot be done. Are you sure? The list should be inside `<sjg:gridColumn>` and it is dynamic :) Also **the selected** value of this list should be retrieved while editing of rows.

Comment: @Tiny, refer this link as : http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-optiontransferselect-example/

Comment: That example doesn't say anything about `<sjg:grid>` available in [`struts2-jquery-grid`](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/detail?name=struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar&can=2&q=) plugin.

Comment: Could you please provide me a very simple workable example? I hope you must have already implemented this at least once, since it is a basic thing.

Comment: try this sample one: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/

Comment: I have already done that several times somewhere else in my application but there nothing about [`<sjg:grid>`](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the documentation connected with `gridColumn` and `editoptions` property:

> **dataUrl**
>
> This option is valid only for elements of type select - i.e.,
>   edittype:select and should be the URL to get the AJAX data for the
>   select element. The data is obtained via an AJAX call and should be a
>   valid HTML select element with the desired options One…. You can use option group.

your action has to return valid `select` element. 
That means, that your `Product.jsp` result need to look like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<s:select list="categories" key="id" value="name"/>
```

Reference: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules

Comment: This can be done, if there is `<s:select>` alone. Can we have `<s:select>` inside a grid column?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the `select` is rendered when there is no `taglib` declaration inside `Product.jsp`, right? I am sure that you have some `taglib` declaration in `JSP` where you have placed `gridColumn` element, then it will work without additional declaration inside `Product.jsp`.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate it in conjunction with an `<sjg:grid>`? I cannot envision this thing. I have implemented such kind of things in JSF and its component library PrimeFaces where there is a `<p:rowEditor>` inside `<p:dataTable>` in which we can put a component of our choice like `<p:selectOneMenu>`. It is a different scenario.